# If we check head==null why don't we check tail==null in Java linkedlist?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I am a beginner in Java and currently completing a Udemy course on DSA. I am learning linked lists and am working on methods to insert and delete nodes to and from linked lists respectively.

From what I have learnt so far I know that we use condition `head==null` to check if the linked list is empty or not.

If the condition `head==null` is true then LinkedList is empty else it is not empty.

However, shouldn't we check whether `tail==null` as well because the tail will always refer to the last node in the LinkedList even after we make `head==null`?

Here is my code:

```
public class SinglyLinkedList{
  public Node head;
  public Node tail;
  public int size;

//Create Linkedlist
  public Node createLL(int num){
    Node node=new Node();
    node.value=num;
    node.next=null;
    head=node;
    tail=node;

    size=1;
    return head;
  }
//Insert Node
  public void insertNode(int num,int location){
    Node node=new Node();
    node.value=num;
    
    if(head==null){//Used to check if linked list is empty or not?
      createLL(num);
      return;
    }

    else if(location==0){
      node.next=head;
      head=node;
    }

    else if(location>=size){
      node.next=null;
      tail.next=node;
      tail=node;
    }

    else{
      Node tempNode=head;
      int index=0;

      while(index<location-1){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
        index++;
      }
     node.next=tempNode.next;
     tempNode.next=node;
    }
    size++;
  }
//Delete Node
  public void deleteNode(int location){
    if(head==null){//Used to check if linked list is empty or not?
      System.out.println("The linked list is not present");
      return;
    }

    else if(location==0){
      head=head.next;
      size--;
      if(size==0){
        tail=null;
      }
    }

    else if(location>=size){
      Node tempNode=head;
      for(int i=0;i<size-1;i++){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
      }
      if(head==null){
        tail=null;
        size--;
        return;
      }
      tempNode.next=null;
      tail=tempNode;
      size--;
    }

    else{
      Node tempNode=head;
      int index=0;

      while(index<location-1){
        tempNode=tempNode.next;
        index++;
      }
      tempNode.next=tempNode.next.next;
      size--;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't need it, if the head is null then the tail is also null

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: How there can be a tail if there is no head. Head will point to the next node like this head-> some node-> tail.

Comment: The list either has a head/tail node, or it doesn't (if there are no nodes). The head/tail node may be the same node (if it's a 1 node list), or they may be a different node, but there's no case where only one of them would exist. So there's no need to check for both.

Comment: Suppose, I have a linked list with many elements. head->node1->node2->node3->tail(node4). Here, the tail is a pointer that points to the last node that is node 4. Now I make head==null which will make tail->node4.

Comment: @SourabhChavan do you mean you test `head == null;` or you assign `head = null;`? If the latter, why would you do that? If you do that, then you must also assign `tail = null;` which has the effect of clearing the list.

Comment: test head==null

Comment: See my answer. If head is null, tail is null. If head isn't null, tail isn't null. No need for two tests when only one is enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Empty list:

```
head -> null
tail -> null
```

Single node list:

```
head -> node1
node1.next -> null
tail -> node1
```

Multi node list:

```
head -> node1
node1.next -> node2
node2.next -> null
tail -> node2
```

Where `->` means "reference points to". So there's no need to check for both head/tail for nullness. If either of them is null, it means the list has no nodes and is empty.

Comment: Yes, but if we make head->null. Node2.next->null and tail is still tail->node2. Because tail->node2 garbage collector will not delete node2 as tail->node2. This is what I have learned. So, shouldn't we set tail=null? Then the linked list will be empty as tail->null and head-> and the garbage collector will get rid of the last node as no node points to it?

Comment: You're responsible for writing correct code so the head/tail pointers are not messed up. But they're either both null, or both non-null in a correct state. You will set `tail = null;` (and `head = null;`) if the list becomes empty. You don't need to check the tail **IF** you are doing things correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Java LinkedList, checking head == null is use for  if the list is empty, head is the starting point of the list. If the head is null, it means there are no elements in the list.

Checking tail == null might not be as straightforward because the tail of the list can be null even if there are elements in the list. In a LinkedList, the tail often points to the last node, and its next reference is null. So, having a null tail doesn't necessarily mean the list is empty ,it means that the last node has not added till now.

Answer (score -1):

Nodes in a Linked-List exist as a value and memory address (for the next node) pair as you have implemented in the program above. For the last node, the end of the list is represented as NULL.

We check if the head is NULL since if the memory address of the next node in the linked list is NULL, then that means the end of the list has been reached. The tail of the linked list will always be NULL since it would represent the end of the list, and there would be no next node to point to.

Comment: I thought that the head points to the first node and tail to the last node of the linked list? How can tail be null if it always points to the last node and head to first node?